# Mule 4 Incorrect date value: 'now() as Date{format: "yyyy-mm-dd"} + |P27D|' for column 'exitdatum'

Tags: mysql, mulesoft, mule4

I am using AnyPoint studio and Im trying to insert a expression into db like this:

```
insert into table_name (exitdate)
values ('now() as Date{format: "yyyy-mm-dd"} + |P27D|')
```

But I'm getting an error: `Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'now() as Date{format: "yyyy-mm-dd"} + |P27D|' for column 'exitdate' at row 1.`

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Now Im getting error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as Date{format "yyyy-mm-dd"} + |P27D|)' at line 2

Answer (score 0):

You are using a DataWeave expression inside the SQL query. You should assign the result of the expression to a parameter and use the parameter instead.

Note that dates don't have a format. The format applies when converting to/from other types, like a String.